# Call to a Member Function getAccessToken() on a non-object

Tags: php, json, google-drive-api

I have been stucked with this for almost a week. I am just a newbie to Google API.

I just want to list my files in Google Drive Folder.

Here is the code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT_URI4);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

// Refresh the user token and grand the privileges
$client->setAccessToken($credentials);
$refreshToken = $drive->getAccessToken()["refreshToken"];

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentials, $client->getAccessToken());
}

$files_list = $service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();

echo json_encode($files_list);
```

I looked at the use_object = false to change it to true but can't find a file that contains the line.

Your help is so much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is $refreshToken ?  you cant get an access token unless you have a refresh token first.